# Why can't I call C# generic list extension on concrete class list?

Tags: c#, list, generics, interface, extension-methods

I extended a concrete class as below

```
public static string ToMyString(this IInterface obj)
{
   return "some string";
}
```

and I am able to call above extension on concrete reference like this

```
Concrete c = new Concrete();    // Concrete is an implementer of IInterface
c.ToMyString();
```

Same way I created another extension like

```
public static string ToMyString(this List<IInterface> obj)
{
   return "some string";
}
```

But I am not able to call this in same way as I did for single concrete object

```
List<Concrete> c = new List<Concrete>();    
c.ToMyString();
```

It's a compile time error!

Comment: Use `ToMyString(this IEnumerable<IInterface> items)`

Comment: @Rango It doesn't work.

Comment: Depends on what you mean with "it doesn't work". It does nothing because you swallow the returned string

Comment: Its a compile time error.

Comment: No, i have tried it. Read the duplicate to learn why it isn't allowed and why `IEnumerable<T>` works( safe generic variance).